# Deployed Silverlight app doesn't work with database after move from local PC to remote server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight, iis, deployment

Yesterday I finished my first Silverlight application. This application communicates with a database (SQL server on another remote server) via Entity model and Domain Service class. When I test it on my PC everything works well. So I deploy this project first to a local place and then after that I move it to the remote server.

The problem is after this move to the server, WCF RIA does not communicate with server (callback throws an error that server was not found - nothing more).

How can I find out where this error is coming from; I´m a little desperate, because I´ve never worked with IIS. I tried the Web Deploy option, but it cannot connect to the remote server. 
On my local PC I have IIS 8 Express and on remote server where I need move the website is IIS 7 (MS Server 2008).

My Web.Config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ISPRSWebFormTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sql.fce.cz\\MSSQL2012,1433;initial catalog=testDB;user id=reviewer;password=xxxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First thing I would do is ping sql.fce.cz from the server you've deployed your app on and ensure a connection can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Pls provide more error infos for diagnosing.
Besides, you must to double check following settings.
1. ConnectionString. Pls confirm the connection string is correct and able to connect to the remote server.
2. Web service. Pls try to access the svc file in IE, confirm the web service is working well.

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't give me any more information. But maybe the problem will be on the IIS on the remote server.